# Is Cramer-Shoup Lite IND-CCA secure?

Tags: chosen-ciphertext-attack, cramer-shoup

Recently, I studied about Cramer-Shoup encryption scheme. Then, I read a book which mentioned a simpler version of this scheme, the Cramer-Shoup Lite encryption scheme.
I was wondering if there is somewhere a formal proof of IND-CCA security of Cramer-Shoup Lite encryption scheme.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Cramer-Shoup lite is CCA1 secure (not CCA2).

Comment: Thank you, I have found that too, but I am trying to find a (formal) proof of this.

Answer (score 1):

It's far from a full proof, but if you use the sketch from [Boaz Barak's lecture notes](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall07/cos433/lec22.pdf), together with the full proof of the full scheme from the Cramer-Shoup paper, you should be able to work it out.